# How to set date upon form submission

Tags: jquery, python, html

Problem: when I click on a date in the calendar, the date will set to the specified date. When I click outside of the date (anywhere else on the form) it will default back to today's date, and in the browser console I can see the HTML value being set to today's date. And upon submission of the form, the logs come back as the current date as well.

How do I set up JS to set the date upon submission of the form and when clicking outside of the calendar?

JS:

```
function set_date() {
    var end_date = $('#nonRecurDateCalendar').val;
    return end_date
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>    
    <input type="date" style="width:100px;" name="payoff_date" value="[DATE_REPLACE]" id="nonRecurDateCalendar" class="dateedit" onChange="checkforerror()">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                webcalendar_init("nonRecurDateCalendar","[DATE_REPLACE]");
            </script>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate Payoff" name="calc_payoff" id="calc_payoff" onclick="return checkForm();"  [SUBMIT_DISABLE_REPLACE] />
</td>
```

Python:

```
#build min and max dates.
try:
    days_offset = int(step_obj.p_data.path_config_data['days_offset'])
except:
    days_offset = 30
step_obj.p_data.max_date = (datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=days_offset))
step_obj.p_data.max_date_str = step_obj.p_data.max_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

step_obj.p_data.min_date = datetime.date.today()
step_obj.p_data.min_date_str = step_obj.p_data.min_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

if 'payoff_date' not in step_obj.p_data.validated_form_data:
    step_obj.p_data.form_date = step_obj.p_data.min_date_str
    step_obj.write_line(["DEBUG PAYOFF Min DATE:", step_obj.p_data.min_date_str])
else:
    step_obj.p_data.form_date = step_obj.p_data.validated_form_data['payoff_date']
    step_obj.write_line(["DEBUG PAYOFF DATE:",
        step_obj.p_data.validated_form_data['payoff_date']])
```